# Multiple verifications under one test - if one of the verification fails how to continue to verify the remaining

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, maven

I'm working with selenium/Java /TestNG Maven project.

Main function calls multiple validation from java class. If any one of the verification fails, the remaining are skipped.

From the below code if,
`autoRenewalChargedPage.selectUseCase(testDataMap);` , fails remaining to verifications are skipping.

Note: I tried `softassert.assertall`.This doesn't work

Main Function:

```java
package com.truist.eb.truistweb.content;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import com.truist.base.tests.BaseTest;
import com.truist.base.utility.ExcelUtils;

public class AutoRenewalChargedPageTests extends BaseTest {
    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

    @Test(dataProvider = "autoRenewalChargedtestdata", priority = 1)
    public void autoRenewalChargedTest(String key, Map<String, List<String>> testDataMap) throws InterruptedException {
        AutoRenewalChargedPage autoRenewalChargedPage = new AutoRenewalChargedPage(getDriver());

        autoRenewalChargedPage.selectUseCase(testDataMap);
        autoRenewalChargedPage.validateTeaserUC1(testDataMap);
        autoRenewalChargedPage.validateStoryUC1(testDataMap);
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }

    // Data Providers

    @DataProvider(name = "autoRenewalChargedtestdata")
    public Object[][] autoRenewalChargedTestData() throws Exception {
        Map<String, List<String>> testDataMap = ExcelUtils.getTestDataMap(webContentTestDataFile,
                "AutoRenewalChargedPage");
        Object[][] testData = new Object[1][2];
        testData[0][0] = "testData";
        testData[0][1] = testDataMap;
        return testData;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue verifying the remaining validations even if one verification fails, you can modify your code to catch the exceptions thrown during the verifications and handle them appropriately. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "autoRenewalChargedtestdata", priority = 1)
public void autoRenewalChargedTest(String key, Map<String, List<String>> testDataMap) throws InterruptedException {
    AutoRenewalChargedPage autoRenewalChargedPage = new AutoRenewalChargedPage(getDriver());
    boolean overallVerificationStatus = true; // Flag to track overall verification status

    try {
        autoRenewalChargedPage.selectUseCase(testDataMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        overallVerificationStatus = false;
        // Log or report the verification failure
    }

    try {
        autoRenewalChargedPage.validateTeaserUC1(testDataMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        overallVerificationStatus = false;
        // Log or report the verification failure
    }

    try {
        autoRenewalChargedPage.validateStoryUC1(testDataMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        overallVerificationStatus = false;
        // Log or report the verification failure
    }

    // Assert the overall verification status
    softAssert.assertTrue(overallVerificationStatus);

    // Perform other assertions or actions as needed
    // softAssert.assertEquals(...);
    // softAssert.assertTrue(...);

    softAssert.assertAll();
}
```

In this approach, each verification is enclosed within a separate try-catch block. If any verification fails and throws an exception, the catch block will be executed, and the `overallVerificationStatus` flag will be set to `false`. By the end of the test, the `softAssert.assertTrue(overallVerificationStatus)` assertion will be performed to check the overall verification status. If the flag is `false`, it means at least one verification failed, and the test will be marked as a failure.

By implementing this solution, you will be able to continue executing the remaining verifications even if one of them fails. Remember to handle exceptions appropriately and log/report the verification failures for further analysis.

Comment: TY, but this solution doesn't work. Still the same issue.

Comment: autoRenewalChargedPage.validateTeaserUC1 , when this executes and fails the validation , softassert.assert all is validating only for this .below is the code for 'validateTeaser UC1'

Comment: public void validateTeaserUC1(Map<String, List<String>> testDataMap) throws InterruptedException {

  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='eb-teaser-container']/iframe")));
  softAssert.assertEquals(driver
    .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-perso-block-id='title']//*[@class='pstory-block-content']")).getText(),
    testDataMap.get("Teaser_Title").get(0), "Teaser Title doesn't match");

  softAssert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "//*[@class='pstory-block-frame pstory-block-text perso-teaser-text']//*[@class= 'pstory-block-content']"))

Comment: .getText(), testDataMap.get("Teaser Text").get(0), "Teaser Text doesn't match");

  softAssert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"staticLink\"]")).getText(),
    testDataMap.get("Teaser_CTA").get(0), "Teaser CTA name  doesn't match");

  driver.switchTo().parentFrame();

  softAssert.assertAll();

  Thread.sleep(2000);

 }